# Cloud SQL instance 2nd Generation ALTERNATIVE activation policy "ON DEMAND"

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have problem with Cloud SQL billing.

My Cloud SQL has used all 720 Hours running machine (**db-g1-small** : changed from db-n1-standard-1 recently)

[image]

I've found accordding to [Cloud SQL Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-settings#activation-policy-2ndgen) that

> For Second Generation instances, the activation policy is used only to start or stop the instance.

So without **`ON_DEMAND`** policy of the First Generation, how can I reduce these costs on my Cloud SQL instance?

**PS.** Look like my cloud server not automatically down because it stay 4 sleep connections
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Indeed for second generation instances of Cloud SQL, the only activation policies available are `ALWAYS` and `NEVER`, so it's not possible anymore to leave that kind of instance handling entirely on Cloud SQL's hands.

However you can create a workaround for this by executing a cron job that turns the instances on/off on a fixed schedule. Eg: you can run a cron job that runs on friday night to shutdown the instance and on monday morning to shut it back on.

You can use the following command to do so:

```
gcloud sql instances patch [INSTANCE_NAME] --activation-policy [ACTIVATION_POLICY_VALUE]
```

Moreover, you can create a feature request on Google Cloud's [Public Issue Tracker System](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0) to re-include that functionality on Cloud SQL in the future, but there are no guaratees that this will happen.

Comment: That as I want to say but I need to Create Cloud VM and control it?

Comment: I did not understood your follow-up question very well, so please clarify it if I undertood it wrong. But if you want to check how to create a cron job you can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating), and you do not need a instance to do it, Cloud Scheduler hadles that for you.